# Creating a custom confirmation box using jquery,css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, confirm

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jj64k/5/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.del').click(function () {

         // var id = $(this).attr('cmnt-id');
         // $.post(url,{
         //data sent
         //},function(data){
         //remove the comment div

         //show the confirm box and ask for that question now
         confirmBox("Sure wanna delete this?");
         $('#console').append('deleted<br />');
         //});
     });

 });

 function confirmBox(text) {
     var c = $('.confirm');
     c.children('.confirm-text').text(text);
     c.show();
 }
```

When i click delete i want to confirm first and then delete by appending `delete` in `#console`.

I dont want any custom browser `confirm()` or any ***plugins***.

But i cannot get how to implement the confirm box into action please help!

**UPDATE**

if i have something like this

`<button data-id="10" id="send">SEND</button>`

**jQuery**

```
$('.send').click(){
   var data_id = $(this).attr('data-id');

   $.post(url{
       data_id : data_id
   },function(){data}{

     $('#console').append('sent');    

   });
};
```

if i have something like this then how will i implement the `confirmbox` function in here ?

Comment: You can pass a function that performs the delete into your confirmBox function.  Only call the passed in delete function if yes button has been clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Add click event listeners for the *Yes* button and *No* button of your confirm box.

Like this(jQuery):

```
$('.confirm > .yes').click(function () {
    $('#console').append('deleted<br />');

//OR DO WHAT YOU WANT WHEN 'YES' BUTTON IS CLICKED

    $('.confirm').hide();
});
$('.confirm > .no').click(function () {

//OR DO WHAT YOU WANT WHEN 'NO' BUTTON IS CLICKED

    $('.confirm').hide();
});
```

**UPDATE** `// for the sake of "reusability"`

Revised `confirmBox() function` so it would accept two parameters (*the confirm box text*,*the function to execute when yes button is clicked*).

Like:

```
function confirmBox(text,yesFunc) {
    var c = $('.confirm');
    c.children('.confirm-text').text(text);
    c.show();
    $('.confirm > .yes').click(function () {
         yesFunc();
         c.hide();
         yesFunc = function () {};
    });    
    $('.confirm > .no').click(function () {
         c.hide();
         yesFunc = function () {};
    });
}
```

Now call confirmBox() function inside of the event handler where whatever button(delete/create/etc.) is clicked and pass the actions/function of the corresponding button.

LIKE:

```
 $('.del').click(function () {
    confirmBox("Sure wanna delete this?", function () {
    $('#console').append('deleted<br />') //or whatever function
    });
});

$('.cre').click(function () {
    confirmBox("Sure wanna create this?", function () {
    $('#console').append('created<br />'); //or whatever function
    });
});

$('.send').click(function () {
    confirmBox("Sure wanna send this?", function () {
    $('#console').append('sent<br />'); //or whatever function 
    });
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jj64k/15/)**

Comment: but if i want somehthing like that reuses that code... for example if i also have a create button that creates after some confirmation request ? look at this fiddle jsfiddle.net/jj64k/8

Comment: then put the two click event listener inside the event where that specific button is clicked like this : http://jsfiddle.net/jj64k/10/

Comment: but int that writing `yes` and `no` function each and everythime ?

Comment: cannot we send our `different actions` in a function to `confirmBox()` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54086/discussion-between-froient-and-user3560703).

Comment: when i click `delete` and `no` it does not do anything. but when i again click `delete` and `yes` this time it appends `deleted<br />` **two** times

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign the delete function to the 'yes' button

JsFIddle http://jsfiddle.net/jj64k/7/

```
 $('.yes').click(function () {
         $('#console').append('deleted<br />');
         $('.confirm').hide();

     });
```

Comment: but if i want somehthing like that reuses that code... for example if i also have a `create` button that creates after some confirmation request ? look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jj64k/8/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.del').click(function () {
         confirmBox("Sure wanna delete this?", function(){
           // var id = $(this).attr('cmnt-id');
           // $.post(url,{
           //data sent
           //},function(data){
           //remove the comment div

           //show the confirm box and ask for that question now
           $('#console').append('deleted
');
           //});
       });
    });
 });

 function confirmBox(text, yesFunc) {
     var c = $('.confirm');
     c.children('.confirm-text').text(text);
     c.show();

     $(".yes").unbind("click").click(function(){yesFunc(); c.hid();});
     $(".no").click(function(){c.hide();});
 }
```

Comment: but if i want somehthing like that reuses that code... for example if i also have a create button that creates after some confirmation request ? look at this fiddle jsfiddle.net/jj64k/8

Comment: You would pass in any function you want to be called if the yes button is click on the confirm box.  So you have a function that create something then you pass that function in to `confirmBox`.  `$('.cre').click(function(){confirmBox("text you want", function(){/*stuff to do the creating*/}});`

Comment: theres a bug....... just click delete then yes and then again click delete and then yes . you will see that "deleted" is appended 3 times!(but it should do 2 times since u clicked only 2 times) !!

Comment: I forgot to unbind the first click event... Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jj64k/14/)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED to make the confirm box reusable, which required jQuery 1.9.1 instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.del').click(function () {
         //Delete confirm box. Attaching a callback function
         confirmBox("Sure wanna delete this?", function () {
             $('#console').append('deleted<br />');
             $('.confirm').hide();
         });
     });
     $('.cre').click(function () {
         // Create confirm box. Attaching a calling function
         confirmBox("Sure wanna append this?", function () {
             $('#console').append('appended<br />');
             $('.confirm').hide();
         });
     });
     // Genetic No button event
     $('.no').click(function () {
         $('.confirm').hide();
     });
 });

 // Notice the confirmBox function now takes a callback function for the yes button click event
 function confirmBox(text, callback) {
     var c = $('.confirm');
     c.children('.confirm-text').text(text);
     c.show();
     $(document).off('click', '.yes');           // Cancel previous click event listener
     $(document).on('click', '.yes', callback);  // New click event listener setup
 }
```

See working code at:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnE99/9/)

Comment: but if i want somehthing like that reuses that code... for example if i also have a create button that creates after some confirmation request ? look at this fiddle jsfiddle.net/jj64k/8

Comment: you will need to attach a callback to the yes and no button clicks instead.

Comment: The answer has been updated to make the confirmBox reusable by adding callback parameter. Notice the JQuery was updated to 1.9.1 to use the event delegation feature.

Comment: Notice how the "Yes" button click event handler is passed as a callback function, which is attached at the time when the function 'confirmBox()' is called.

Comment: but what if i want to pass different numbers parameters in `delete` and `create` buttons `callback` ?

Comment: Whenever you call the function confirmBox(), you will need to pass 2 paremeters, a string that is used to display on the confirmation box, and a callback function which lists the operations to be executed when the yes button is clicked.

Comment: yes i got it so i the situation is like i want some `$.post` or `$.get` request to happen on clicking another button `AJAX` which sends parameters to php. Then how will i pass the parameters to `callback` ?

Comment: not clear on what you mean by "pass the parameters to callback".

Comment: Inside the post handling function, you would be calling 'confirmBox(<string>, <callback>)' as usual, For the <callback> function pass the returned "data" and have the callback function manages the data dynamically. So, it would look like "confirmBox("bla bla", function(data){ // set the behaviors based o the data content ... });

Comment: but since `created` and `deleted` does not have parameters in callback and `send` has there would be any problem ?

Comment: No. You will need to learn about closure in JavaScript. Here is a good link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work